# Android: onClick image make invisible Textview

Tags: android, view, onclick, onclicklistener, invisible

I've done an Activity with an image in full screen and below a textview with its description. What I want is to make invisible textview when I click on the image. I have placed a Toast and there goes the code, but is not invisible. What can be the error? thanks

```
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup view, int position) {

        View imageLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.ampliar_imagen, view, false);
        assert imageLayout != null;

        imageView = (TouchImageView) imageLayout.findViewById(R.id.imagenFullScreen);

        info = (TextView) imageLayout.findViewById(R.id.textoInfoImagen);

                    final ProgressBar spinner = (ProgressBar) imageLayout.findViewById(R.id.cargandoFoto);
        imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Toast.makeText(ImagePagerActivity.this, "CLICK", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                info.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

        });

        imageLoader.displayImage(images[position], imageView, options, new SimpleImageLoadingListener() {

            @Override
            public void onLoadingStarted(String imageUri, View view) {
                spinner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

            @Override
            public void onLoadingFailed(String imageUri, View view, FailReason failReason) {

                Toast.makeText(ImagePagerActivity.this, "Error al cargar la imagen", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

            @Override
            public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view, Bitmap loadedImage) {
                spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        });

        view.addView(imageLayout, 0);
        return imageLayout;
    }
```

**XML**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/negro" >

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <imagenes.TouchImageView
        android:id="@+id/imagenFullScreen"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/cargandoFoto"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:visibility="gone" />
</FrameLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textoInfoImagen"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="@color/grisTransparente"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:paddingBottom="3dp"
    android:paddingTop="3dp"
    android:text="AAAA"
    android:textColor="@color/blanco"
    android:textSize="13sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: post your xml code...

Comment: ok. the code is edited

Comment: Buddy you hvnt set any text in the TextView so you are not able to see the effect of SetVisibility() function

Comment: I charge the text and I see the text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define the textview in oclick event like this

```
  imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

 TextView info = (TextView) imageLayout.findViewById(R.id.textoInfoImagen);
 info.setVisibility(View.GONE);//or you can invisible,

 }

        });
```

Comment: @User3327667 when you try this , please turn back

Answer (score 1):

I will suggest you to set your imageLayout as tag of imageView and in onClick of image view get your textview from tag layout and then set its visibility gone or invisible. try this.

```
 imageView = (TouchImageView) imageLayout.findViewById(R.id.imagenFullScreen);
 info = (TextView) imageLayout.findViewById(R.id.textoInfoImagen);  
 imageView.setTag(info);
 imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

         TextView tv = (TextView)v.getTag();
         tv.setVisibility(View.GONE);

     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this

```
info.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

use this:-

```
info.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

Set Visibility to your textview in xml:-

```
   <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textoInfoImagen"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@color/grisTransparente"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:paddingBottom="3dp"
        android:paddingTop="3dp"
        android:text=""
        **android:visibility="visible"**
        android:textColor="@color/blanco"
        android:textSize="13sp" />
```

Answer (score 0):

in your xml set ,

```
      android:visibility="true"
      //in textview
```

and in your activity,

```
              info.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

Comment: set info.setalpha(0.0f); //for invisible

Comment: instead of   android:visibility="true"
      //in textview
and in your activity,

              info.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

Answer (score 0):

set 
    info.setalpha(0.0f);
    //for invisible

set 
        info.setalpha(1.0f);
          //for visible

Comment: Thanks, but it not runs

Answer (score 0):

```
Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "CLICK", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```